# How to find zsh environmental variable from bash script?

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables, zsh

I'm writing a bash installation script that handles installation for different shells. I need to copy a function into zsh's $fpath.

I thought I had a solution with `/usr/bin/env zsh -c "echo $fpath"` but that only works within zsh and not bash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use single quotes, not double quotes. `bash` is substituting the `$fpath` that it knows about which is probably empty.

```
/usr/bin/env zsh -c 'echo $fpath'
```